# Pagination and a Where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I there, im using eloquent to create a query where gets the galleries from a specific user_id, but i want also to implement the pagination, but is not working the way im doing.

ex:

```
$galleries =  Gallery::paginate(10)->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->get();
```

Comment: $galleries = Gallery::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(10);

Answer (score 3):

```
$galleries = Gallery::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you are supposed to do :

```
$galleries =  Gallery::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(10);
```

In the view use :

```
{{ $galleries->appends(Input::except('page'))->links() }}
```